# Сопоставление и изменение данных через рефлексию

Tags: java, рефлексия, jackson, lombok

Есть класс User

```
public class User() {
private String name;
private int age;
private long passportNumber;
private ZonedDateTime workStartTime;
// здесь будут сеттеры и геттеры
}
```

Есть json

```
{"name": Alex, "age": 35, "passportNumber": 7745795431, "offset":1}
```

Использую Jackson для десериализации данных из json и Lombok для работы с pojo-классом.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PojoClass pojo = objectMapper.readValue(file, PojoClass.class);
```

Далее происходит итерация по полям pojo и установление в нужные поля класса User.

```
Field[] field = PojoClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
field.setAccessible(true);
Object value = field.get(pojo);
if (field.toString().contains("passportNumber")) {
User.getDocument().setPassportNumber((int) value));
}
if (field.toString().contains("offset")) {
user.setWorkStartTime(now().plusHour((int) value));
}
```

Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека, которая позволит не писать множество if-ов, а сопоставит поля из pojo и User сама?))Вариант с десериализацией json сразу в User вряд-ли подойдет, потому что полей в user много, и менять их нужно на разных уровнях агрегации(как в случае с passportNumber).

Код на java8

Comment: А почему вы добираетесь до атрибутов класса через рефлексию, а не через методы-аксессоры? Что вам мешает повесить аннотацию `@Data`? Преобразование из PojoClass в User делается вручную т.к. структура данных не совпадает. Ну и принято данные, принятые извне, загонять в классы с именем `..Dto`

Comment: @ArchDemon кажется можно написать все сеттеры в классе User и через рефлексию записывать их в user. Через рефлексию хочется сравнивать имена полей в json и сеттеры в  классе User.Почему рефлексия? Ну, во-первых, просто меньше кода, ведь json на самом деле гораздо больше, а во-вторых будет своеобразный контракт на то, что для каждого поля в json есть сеттер в классе User, иначе ошибка. Понимаю что рефлексия это дорого...

Comment: у вас код преобразования PojoClass в User очень неправильный. Не делайте так. `user.setField(pojo.getField())` так нагляднее и понятнее

Comment: @ArchDemon дело в том, что из json прилетает массив параметров для каждого юзера (выборка по id) и нет гарантии что во всех элементах массива будут одинаковые наборы полей. Поэтому думалось использовать рефлексию

Comment: Для этого вы обращаетесь не к json, а к полям класса `PojoClass pojo = objectMapper.readValue(file, PojoClass.class);`. Я вам даю гарантию, что поля класса не меняются в зависимости от пришедшего json

Comment: Безусловно поля класса не будут меняться, но не ясно какой код будет однотипно заполнять состояние юзеров независимо от входящих из json полей данных? Вы предлагаете для каждого  юзера писать код заполнения? а если их 50?

Comment: У юзера один класс, значит один набор полей. А циклы ещё никто не отменял

Comment: {"name": Alex, "age": 35, "passNum": 7745795431, "offset":1}
{"name": Alex, "weight": 77, "socialNum": 7745795431}
Вот массив из данных для двух юзеров. Класс User будет содержать все эти поля. Как по вашему должно происходить заполнение?

Comment: Как я вам показал выше